# Extracting a value from query string using Regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the value from this string using regex but I can't seem to get it right.

string:

```
?Ntt=crockett%20&%20Jones&Rdm=718&searchType=simple&type=search&Ns=&N=&Nrpp=12&No=0&Nr=AND(product.active:1,NOT(record.type:Store))
```

I need the value of `Ntt` which is `crockett%20&%20Jones`.

The regex I have currently is:

```
\?Ntt=(([&%])|([^&=]))*
```

but this results in:

```
?Ntt=crockett%20&%20Jones&Rdm
```

How can I update my regex to produce the value I need?

Comment: the & usually separates inputs in a query string. Are you sure you need `&%20Jones`? IF not, use `[&\?]Ntt=([^&]*)`

Comment: @mankowitz, I do need `&%20Jones` - that's why I'm struggling to find a suitable regex

Comment: How do you know that the second group is part of what you are trying to capture? In other words, how do you know how much you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capturing group based regex like

```php
[&?]Ntt=((?:%20&%20|[^&])*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0wYLaE/4).

Alternatively, you can use a lookbehind based regex like

```php
(?<=[&?]Ntt=)(?:%20&%20|[^&])*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0wYLaE/3/).

**Details**

- `(?<=[&?]Ntt=)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `?` or `&` and then `Ntt=`
- `(?:%20&%20|[^&])*` - a non-capturing group that matches zero or more occurrences of a `%20&%20` substring or any char other than `&`.

Answer (score 0):

`[&\?]Ntt=([^&]*)`

First capture the separator (either ? or &), then capture the key, then capture everything until the next separator.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/VuXQXP/1